# Using Func<T> parameters

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Func in my code that's declared like this:

```
Func<string, int, bool> Filter { get; set; }
```

How can I reach the string and the int variables that are parameters of the Func in order to use them in my code?

Comment: Think of `Filter` as a method. It doesn't have a value for the `string` or the `int` parameters. Those values are passed when the method is called.

Comment: The Func doesn't have string and int *variables* as its parameters. It has string and int *values*. The variables (perhaps - could be literals!) that provided those values should be irrelevant to the Func.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters only *exist* when the function is called... and they're only available within the function. So for example:

```
foo.Filter = (text, length) => text.Length > length;

bool longer = foo.Filter("yes this is long", 5);
```

Here, the value "yes this is long" is the value of the `text` parameter *while the delegate is executing* and likewise the value 5 is the value of the `length` parameter *while it's executing*. At other times, it's a meaningless concept.

What are you really trying to achieve? If you could give us more context, we could almost certainly help you better.

Comment: I'm trying to get a function from the user which supposed to filter some of the elements that I have in my class.
Each element consists of a String and an int ,The problem is that I have only the string part, I want to use this func to update the int part during the invocation of this function.
I know it's not exactly the right way but based the restrictions that I have it seems the only way.

Comment: @YoniPlotkin: Sorry, it's still not really clear to me what's going on. A function which *takes* an `int` shouldn't be relied on to *update* it. Maybe it would be clearer if you could provide a short but complete example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I'll try to explain
I have a component ,user and server classes
the user class looks something like that
    `public class Component{
      string Id { get; }
      int Status { get; }
    }`
and some more functions...

The user class looks like this:
    `public class User{
     string Id { get; }
     IDictionary<string, int> Status { get; }
     IEnumerable<string> RelevantComponents { get; }
     Func<string, ComponentStatus, bool> Filter { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: and there's the server that should connect between the user and the relevant components

    `public class Server{
     List<Component> components;
     List<User> clients;
     void RegisterClient(User client);
     void RegisterComponent(Component comp);
     }`

I want to update the Status dictionary in user class without a direct function between the user and the server, so my goal is to use the setter of the Func to achieve that.
hope it clarifies the situation..

Comment: @YoniPlotkin: It's hard to follow everything in comments. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and then edit your question - preferably with a short but complete example, not just bits and pieces.

Answer (score 4):

You could use an anonymous method:

```
Filter = (string s, int i) => {
    // use s and i here and return a boolean
};
```

or a standard method:

```
public bool Foo(string s, int i)
{
    // use s and i here and return a boolean
}
```

and then you could assign the Filter property to this method:

```
Filter = Foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

See this sample here - http://www.dotnetperls.com/func

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //
    // Create a Func instance that has one parameter and one return value.
    // ... Parameter is an integer, result value is a string.
    //
    Func<int, string> func1 = (x) => string.Format("string = {0}", x);
    //
    // Func instance with two parameters and one result.
    // ... Receives bool and int, returns string.
    //
    Func<bool, int, string> func2 = (b, x) =>
        string.Format("string = {0} and {1}", b, x);
    //
    // Func instance that has no parameters and one result value.
    //
    Func<double> func3 = () => Math.PI / 2;

    //
    // Call the Invoke instance method on the anonymous functions.
    //
    Console.WriteLine(func1.Invoke(5));
    Console.WriteLine(func2.Invoke(true, 10));
    Console.WriteLine(func3.Invoke());
    }
}
```

Comment: You actually don't need to call Invoke, you can just do `func1(5)`.